# Не могу десериализовать JSON в объект структуры на Golang

Tags: golang

Отправляю запрос на api сервер для получения json и вывожу его как строку в консоль.

```
r, err := http.Get("http://localhost:5500/website/actors")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
defer r.Body.Close()

bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

fmt.Println(string(bodyBytes))
```

JSON приходит в таком виде.

```
{
    "actors": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "FName": "1Name",
            "LName": "2Name"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Пытаюсь его десериализовать и вывести в консоль.

```
type Actor struct {
    ID    int    `json:"ID,omitempty"`
    FName string `json:"FName,omitempty"`
    LName string `json:"LName,omitempty"`
}

func (ac *Actor) GetActors() []Actor {

    var actors []Actor

    r, err := http.Get("http://localhost:5500/website/actors")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer r.Body.Close()

    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    json_err := json.Unmarshal(bodyBytes, &actors)
    if json_err != nil {
        fmt.Println(json_err)
    }

    fmt.Println(actors)

    return actors
}
```

Но на выходе я получаю пустой массив []. И при проверке на ошибку, я получаю:

> "json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []model.Actor".

Как исправить данную проблему?

Comment: не могли бы приложить json в виде текста, а не в виде картинки?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor исправил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема в том, что JSON отличается от желаемой структуры.

в JSON есть объект actors, и только внутри него лежат массив Actor. Тогда итоговая структура в golang должна быть в виде `map[string][]Actor`

```
var body = []byte(`{
    "actors": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "FName": "1Name",
            "LName": "2Name"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        },
        {
            "ID": 4,
            "FName": "Test",
            "LName": "Test"
        }
    ]
}`)

type Actor struct {
    ID    int    `json:"ID,omitempty"`
    FName string `json:"FName,omitempty"`
    LName string `json:"LName,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var data map[string][]Actor

    json_err := json.Unmarshal(body, &data)
    if json_err != nil {
        fmt.Println(json_err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)

    for jsonObject, actors := range data {
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("the data for object [%s] is %v", jsonObject, actors))
    }
}
```

вывод

```
the data for object [actors] is [{1 1Name 2Name} {2 Test Test} {3 Test Test} {4 Test Test}]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Comment: всегда пожалуйста. авторов можно благодарить нажав на треугольник сверх(голосовать за)

Comment: а если json равен {"film_years":["2018-07-10","2013-07-10"]}? map[string][]string и map[string]string и даже []string не помогают. Что делать?

Comment: Сначала map[string][]string не работал, теперь заработал. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Если вам важны только десериализаия и вывод, и не важна дальнейшая логика работы с данными, то абсолютно любой корректный json вы можете десериализовать в тип `interface{}` и вывести его на консоль.

Если же в дальнейшем с данными придется как то работать, то изучите API вашего ресурса и опишите соответствующие ему структуры.

У вас уже есть хоршо описанный тип Actor:

```
type Actor struct {
    ID    int    `json:"ID,omitempty"`
    FName string `json:"FName,omitempty"`
    LName string `json:"LName,omitempty"`
}
```

Зачем API вашего ресурса  устроен так, что по эндпоинту `/website/actors` возвращает список имеющий название, и кроме него ничего - понять сложно. Возможно в будущем туда добавятся еще какие-то поля или есть какая-то другая причина. Приведенный json соответствует примерно такому типу:

```
type Actors struct {
    List []Actor `json:"actors"`
    // сюда можно добавить другие поля
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vcY-_kZdrG7)

С примером довольно простого и понятного API сервиса с фильмами можно ознакомится [здесь](https://ghibliapi.herokuapp.com/#). Видно, что все списки возвращаются в чистом виде и могут быть десериализованы именно так, как вы делали в самом начале.